# I am trying to write a recursive function that will return the result of the sum (integer) and takes one argument

Tags: java

I am trying to follow these instructions:
Write a program that will ask the user for the value of an integer n, and compute the sum 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n. The requirement for this lab is that you write a recursive function that returns the result of the sum (integer) and takes one argument, n, of type integer. You will then call the function and print out its results as follows:

int mysum = recursive_addition(n);

System.out.println("The sum 1+2+...+n is: "+ mysum);

the problem is on line 20 because of the error below

```
Main.java:20: error: method main (String[]) Is already defined in class Main
    private static void main (String args[])
                        ^
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a integer: ");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int mysum = recurSum(n);
    System.out.println("The sum 1+2+3+4 is  :" + n );

    }

    public static int recurSum(int n) 
    { 
        if (n <= 0) 
            return n; 
        return n + recurSum(n - 1); 
    } 

    public static void main (String args[]) 
    { 
        int n = 5; 
        System.out.println(recurSum(n)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have defined the method 'public static void main(String[] args)' twice, once as the first method, then again as the last method. You're not allowed to do this, as your error states. Delete the last one.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler stated, you are duplicating the main entry points of your application.

Just remove the last main function and modify as follow

Here is the working code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a integer: ");
    int n = 5; // Just put there the number
    int mysum = recurSum(n);
    System.out.println("The sum 1+2+3+4 is  :" + n );

    }

    public static int recurSum(int n) 
    { 
        if (n <= 0) 
            return n; 
        return n + recurSum(n - 1); 
    } 

}
```